# iOS: Custom Table Cell 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableView with a custom TableViewCell. I'm not using an .xib file to lay this out. The problem is when the table is supposed to load I get the following error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage nsli_superitem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x91899b0'` I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Here is the .m file for the cell.

```
#import "TCMExhibitListCell.h"

@implementation TCMExhibitListCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    [self setListImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    [self setTitleLabel:[[UILabel alloc] init]];


    NSDictionary *names = @{@"listImage" : [self listImage]};

    NSString *fmt = @"H:|-0-[listImage]";

    NSArray *imgH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:fmt
                                                            options:0
                                                            metrics:nil
                                                              views:names];
    [[self contentView] addConstraints:imgH];
}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Here's where the cell gets loaded in the tableview controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
TCMExhibitListCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TCMExhibitListCell"];

if (!c) {
    c = [[TCMExhibitListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:@"TCMExhibitListCell"];
}

TCMExhibitRemote *e = [[self exhibits] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

NSString *imageFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg",[[TCMExhibitFeedStore sharedStore] imagePathByType:@"listImage"],[e image]];

[c setListImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageFile]];

return c;
}
```

Comment: this is an odd thing to do if you want blank start content `[self setListImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];[self setTitleLabel:[[UILabel alloc] init]];`  . Try `[self setListImage:nil]; [self setTitleLabel:nil];`

Comment: That created a different error. `[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'` I did it as above because I thought I needed to allocate and initialize the UI components to be able to set them later. listImage is a UIImage and titleLabel is a UILabel both declared as properties in the TCMExhibitListCell.h file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you do a little googling, you'll see that `nsli_superitem` is associated with auto-layout. Which points you towards `[[self contentView] addConstraints:imgH];`, which points you towards `NSString *fmt = @"H:|-0-[listImage]";`, and on to `[self setListImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];`.

I.e. you can't set a layout based on an image, because it isn't a UI item.

You should probably be doing the layout based on an image view view somewhere...

Comment: For me it was the problem that I added the constraints to the view controller and not on the view itself.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I was trying to use a `UIViewController` in a constraint using Visual Format Language.  Changing the constraint to use the UIViewController's `view` fixed the crash:

```
containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[playerVC]-0-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["playerVC" : playerVC.view])) // note playerVC.view here, not playerVC
```

Answer (score 0):

I do think that you forget to set this.

```
self.listImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```